# Issue using .split() to get a username containing many spaces (Discord.js in NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm working on a feature of my Discord Bot, which returns the League of Legends statistics of a player when you write the following command `!lolid [enter_username_here]` in a Discord chat room,

I succeeded to do it for a person which has a username in 1 word, but unfortunately for me a League of Legends username can have spaces (example of possible username: `I AM A GOD`),

When a user types the following command `!lolid [enter_username_here]`, i get it in my JS file as `message.content` variable, so with `message.content.split(" ")[1];` I can get the username he wrote,

**But how can I do if the username contains many spaces ? Thanks,**

Part of involved code :

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!lolid")) {
    console.log(message.content.split(" ")); => if someone types !lolid 1 2 3, it returns ["lolid", "1", "2", "3"];
    const username = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    const promise1 = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(await getSummonerId(username)); => returns id needed to do the request for the stats
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just remove the command part:

```js
const username = message.content.slice(7);
```

or

```js
const username = message.content.split("!lolid ")[1];
```

or

```js
const username = message.content.replace(/\!lolid\s/, "");
```

---

<sub>Thanks to [@GACy20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13270392/gacy20) for the first suggestion</sub>

Comment: Actually, in that code OP already knows that `message.content` starts with `!lolid ` so just use `message.content.slice(7)`

Comment: thank you, i marked your solution as answer

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, leveraging on ES6 syntax:

```js
const msg = "!lolid I AM GOD"
const [cmd, ...ids] = msg.split(" ")
const id = ids.join(" ");

console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only taking the input of the username in your code, then you can just slice off the first element, and use join the rest of it to work.
So like

```js
const username = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
```

This removes the first argument, which is your `!lolid`. That would leave your username only for you to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really into discord bots but since you know what is the length of "!lolid ", can't you just use "message.content.slice(7) or something?